# S3 updated with SSL but updates to raw html not propagating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate

So I've had a S3 setup for a static page with a registered domain for well over a year without any issues. However I've updated my site so that it now has a free SSL certificate via AWS certificate manager / Cloudfront.

My issue now is that if I update my index.html, save the changes and refresh my https://www.example.com the page doesn't reflect the changes. While if I create a new page, e g test.html this loads and can be seen at https://www.example.com/test.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront is a CDN that will cache your website. You need to [invalidate the CloudFront cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) when you make changes to your site.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I didn't release that. I'll investigate this further.